# Getting "oauth_problem=Consumer+key+has+expired" Error in Magento 2 Auth 1.0

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, oauth

I am getting **"oauth_problem=Consumer+key+has+expired"** auth 1.0 in Magento2.

Please see below screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Anyone solved this, please help!

Answer (score 1):

We are also facing this issue and find the solution for this. But this is default magento2 issue.

Please find the link below.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13961

Comment: You found any solution for this?

Comment: Debugging the Magento2 code myself. once done, i will let you know.